# jquery ias Infinite scrolling stops at page 2

Tags: jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

i'm using jquery ias for infinite scrolling + isotope.
When loading the content all works loading page 2, but it stops loading further pages.
[here is the page](http://twitstat.it/afo/more.php?next=17). I'm trying everything but without success.
Any idea to sort out this issue?

This is the js code i'm using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/isotope.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ias.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {               
    var $container = $('#content');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.afo',
    });
});
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '#content',
        item: '.afo',
        pagination: '.nav',
        next: '#nextpage',
        loader: '<img src="./images/loader.gif"/>',
        triggerPageThreshold: 5,

        onRenderComplete: function(items) {
            var $newElems = jQuery(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
              // show elems now they're ready
              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              jQuery("#content").isotope('appended', $newElems );
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved that problem? If so it would be very nice if you would share the answer with all of us! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your page and I think it's because your html isn't valid: it doesn't contain a body tag for example.